# Twitter-Bootstrap: Two dropdown-toggle buttons side by side not working properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

**Intro:** One of the parts of my website requires a small toolbar featuring two dropdown menus side-by side. I tried to achieve this by the following markup (simplified):

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-mini dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span id="uniqueId">Text1</span> <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a onclick="javascript:someFunction()">Item1</a></li>
        <li><a onclick="javascript:someFunction()">Item2</a></li>
        ...
    </ul>
    <button class="btn btn-mini dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span id="uniqueId2">Text2</span> <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a onclick="javascript:someOtherFunction()">Item1</a></li>
        <li><a onclick="javascript:someOtherFunction()">Item2</a></li>
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'd like to get a nice-looking two-buttons toolbar with rounded corners only on outer sides of the toolbar.

**Problem:**

When I click on either button, both buttons are displayed as "pressed" and I can not visually distinguish which one I have just clicked. All the other functionality is working OK - i.e. a menu is shown correctly and with correct options.

Is there any way to make those buttons changing their styles separately?

**Update:**

I do know that it's very well possible to get this working by splitting my buttons into two `btn-group`s or (as @Sherbrow suggested) by using divs. [Bootstrap documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonGroups) also suggests

> Buttons with dropdowns must be individually wrapped in their own .btn-group within a .btn-toolbar for proper rendering.

and I'd like to know - is it possible to somehow avoid this individual wrapping and have two properly behaving dropdowns inside a single btn-group?

I think that I'm asking about quite non-standard and undocumented behavior and I'll accept an answer "that's impossible" if no-one can suggest a way to do that.

Comment: Why have you tagged your question with ASP.NET MVC? Show your generated markup and CSS. This way people that don't know ASp.NET MVC could also help you in designing nice looking stuff.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: Thanks for the tip, will do that right away

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You forgot your `.dropdown` wrapper.

**Update 2** : forgot some code for groups. And made a [gist (github)](https://gist.github.com/3035209)

**Update** : made a better wrapping, and styling like buttons. This is basically another button-type styling, but without the baggage of the `.btn` class.

```html
<div class="btn-group">
    <div class="dropdown dropdown-btn">
        <div class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span id="uniqueId">Text1</span><span class="caret"/>
        </div >
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a onclick="javascript:someFunction()">Item1</a></li>
            <li><a onclick="javascript:someFunction()">Item2</a></li>
            <!-- ... -->
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown dropdown-btn">
        <div class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span id="uniqueId2">Text2</span><span class="caret"/>
        </div >
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a onclick="javascript:someOtherFunction()">Item1</a></li>
            <li><a onclick="javascript:someOtherFunction()">Item2</a></li>
            <!-- ... -->
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

with a big css adjustement (buttons.less and button-groups.less reused changing `.btn` to `.dropdown-btn` from [here (github)](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/tree/master/less)):

```css
.dropdown-btn {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    /* IE7 inline-block hack */
    *zoom: 1;
    padding: 4px 10px 4px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 18px;
    *line-height: 20px;
    color: #333333;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#ffffff), to(#e6e6e6));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#e6e6e6', GradientType=0);
    border-color: #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6 #bfbfbf;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    *background-color: #e6e6e6;
    /* Darken IE7 buttons by default so they stand out more given they won't have borders */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false);
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    *border: 0;
    border-bottom-color: #b3b3b3;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    *margin-left: .3em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}
.dropdown-btn:hover,
.dropdown-btn:active,
.dropdown-btn.active,
.dropdown-btn.disabled,
.dropdown-btn[disabled] {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    *background-color: #d9d9d9;
}
.dropdown-btn:active,
.dropdown-btn.active { background-color: #cccccc \9 }
.dropdown-btn:first-child { *margin-left: 0 }
.dropdown-btn:hover {
    color: #333333;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    *background-color: #d9d9d9;
    /* Buttons in IE7 don't get borders, so darken on hover */
    background-position: 0 -15px;
    -webkit-transition: background-position 0.1s linear;
    -moz-transition: background-position 0.1s linear;
    -ms-transition: background-position 0.1s linear;
    -o-transition: background-position 0.1s linear;
    transition: background-position 0.1s linear;
}
.dropdown-btn:focus {
    outline: thin dotted #333;
    outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
    outline-offset: -2px;
}
.dropdown-btn.active,
.dropdown-btn:active {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    background-color: #d9d9d9 \9;
    background-image: none;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}
.dropdown-btn.disabled,
.dropdown-btn[disabled] {
    cursor: default;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    background-image: none;
    opacity: 0.65;
    filter: alpha(opacity=65);
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
.dropdown-btn-large {
    padding: 9px 14px;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: normal;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.dropdown-btn-large [class^="icon-"] { margin-top: 1px }
.dropdown-btn-small {
    padding: 5px 9px;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 16px;
}
.dropdown-btn-small [class^="icon-"] { margin-top: -1px }
.dropdown-btn-mini {
    padding: 2px 6px;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 14px;
}
.dropdown-btn-primary,
.dropdown-btn-primary:hover,
.dropdown-btn-warning,
.dropdown-btn-warning:hover,
.dropdown-btn-danger,
.dropdown-btn-danger:hover,
.dropdown-btn-success,
.dropdown-btn-success:hover,
.dropdown-btn-info,
.dropdown-btn-info:hover,
.dropdown-btn-inverse,
.dropdown-btn-inverse:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.dropdown-btn-primary.active,
.dropdown-btn-warning.active,
.dropdown-btn-danger.active,
.dropdown-btn-success.active,
.dropdown-btn-info.active,
.dropdown-btn-inverse.active { color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75) }
.dropdown-btn {
    border-color: #ccc;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.dropdown-btn-primary {
    background-color: #0074cc;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0055cc);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0055cc);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#0088cc), to(#0055cc));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0055cc);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0055cc);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0055cc);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0088cc', endColorstr='#0055cc', GradientType=0);
    border-color: #0055cc #0055cc #003580;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    *background-color: #0055cc;
    /* Darken IE7 buttons by default so they stand out more given they won't have borders */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false);
}
.dropdown-btn-primary:hover,
.dropdown-btn-primary:active,
.dropdown-btn-primary.active,
.dropdown-btn-primary.disabled,
.dropdown-btn-primary[disabled] {
    background-color: #0055cc;
    *background-color: #004ab3;
}
.dropdown-btn-primary:active,
.dropdown-btn-primary.active { background-color: #004099 \9 }
.dropdown-btn-warning {
    background-color: #faa732;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fbb450, #f89406);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fbb450, #f89406);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#fbb450), to(#f89406));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fbb450, #f89406);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fbb450, #f89406);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #fbb450, #f89406);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fbb450', endColorstr='#f89406', GradientType=0);
    border-color: #f89406 #f89406 #ad6704;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    *background-color: #f89406;
    /* Darken IE7 buttons by default so they stand out more given they won't have borders */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false);
}
.dropdown-btn-warning:hover,
.dropdown-btn-warning:active,
.dropdown-btn-warning.active,
.dropdown-btn-warning.disabled,
.dropdown-btn-warning[disabled] {
    background-color: #f89406;
    *background-color: #df8505;
}
.dropdown-btn-warning:active,
.dropdown-btn-warning.active { background-color: #c67605 \9 }
.dropdown-btn-danger {
    background-color: #da4f49;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ee5f5b, #bd362f);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ee5f5b, #bd362f);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#ee5f5b), to(#bd362f));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ee5f5b, #bd362f);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ee5f5b, #bd362f);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #ee5f5b, #bd362f);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ee5f5b', endColorstr='#bd362f', GradientType=0);
    border-color: #bd362f #bd362f #802420;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    *background-color: #bd362f;
    /* Darken IE7 buttons by default so they stand out more given they won't have borders */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false);
}
.dropdown-btn-danger:hover,
.dropdown-btn-danger:active,
.dropdown-btn-danger.active,
.dropdown-btn-danger.disabled,
.dropdown-btn-danger[disabled] {
    background-color: #bd362f;
    *background-color: #a9302a;
}
.dropdown-btn-danger:active,
.dropdown-btn-danger.active { background-color: #942a25 \9 }
.dropdown-btn-success {
    background-color: #5bb75b;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #62c462, #51a351);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #62c462, #51a351);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#62c462), to(#51a351));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #62c462, #51a351);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #62c462, #51a351);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #62c462, #51a351);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#62c462', endColorstr='#51a351', GradientType=0);
    border-color: #51a351 #51a351 #387038;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    *background-color: #51a351;
    /* Darken IE7 buttons by default so they stand out more given they won't have borders */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false);
}
.dropdown-btn-success:hover,
.dropdown-btn-success:active,
.dropdown-btn-success.active,
.dropdown-btn-success.disabled,
.dropdown-btn-success[disabled] {
    background-color: #51a351;
    *background-color: #499249;
}
.dropdown-btn-success:active,
.dropdown-btn-success.active { background-color: #408140 \9 }
.dropdown-btn-info {
    background-color: #49afcd;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #5bc0de, #2f96b4);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #5bc0de, #2f96b4);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#5bc0de), to(#2f96b4));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #5bc0de, #2f96b4);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #5bc0de, #2f96b4);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #5bc0de, #2f96b4);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#5bc0de', endColorstr='#2f96b4', GradientType=0);
    border-color: #2f96b4 #2f96b4 #1f6377;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    *background-color: #2f96b4;
    /* Darken IE7 buttons by default so they stand out more given they won't have borders */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false);
}
.dropdown-btn-info:hover,
.dropdown-btn-info:active,
.dropdown-btn-info.active,
.dropdown-btn-info.disabled,
.dropdown-btn-info[disabled] {
    background-color: #2f96b4;
    *background-color: #2a85a0;
}
.dropdown-btn-info:active,
.dropdown-btn-info.active { background-color: #24748c \9 }
.dropdown-btn-inverse {
    background-color: #414141;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #555555, #222222);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #555555, #222222);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#555555), to(#222222));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #555555, #222222);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #555555, #222222);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #555555, #222222);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#555555', endColorstr='#222222', GradientType=0);
    border-color: #222222 #222222 #000000;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    *background-color: #222222;
    /* Darken IE7 buttons by default so they stand out more given they won't have borders */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false);
}
.dropdown-btn-inverse:hover,
.dropdown-btn-inverse:active,
.dropdown-btn-inverse.active,
.dropdown-btn-inverse.disabled,
.dropdown-btn-inverse[disabled] {
    background-color: #222222;
    *background-color: #151515;
}
.dropdown-btn-inverse:active,
.dropdown-btn-inverse.active { background-color: #080808 \9 }
button.dropdown-btn,
input[type="submit"].dropdown-btn {
    *padding-top: 2px;
    *padding-bottom: 2px;
}
button.dropdown-btn::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="submit"].dropdown-btn::-moz-focus-inner {
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
button.dropdown-btn.dropdown-btn-large,
input[type="submit"].dropdown-btn.dropdown-btn-large {
    *padding-top: 7px;
    *padding-bottom: 7px;
}
button.dropdown-btn.dropdown-btn-small,
input[type="submit"].dropdown-btn.dropdown-btn-small {
    *padding-top: 3px;
    *padding-bottom: 3px;
}
button.dropdown-btn.dropdown-btn-mini,
input[type="submit"].dropdown-btn.dropdown-btn-mini {
    *padding-top: 1px;
    *padding-bottom: 1px;
}
.btn-group {
    position: relative;
    *zoom: 1;
    *margin-left: .3em;
}
.btn-group:before,
.btn-group:after {
    display: table;
    content: "";
}
.btn-group:after { clear: both }
.btn-group:first-child { *margin-left: 0 }
.btn-group + .btn-group { margin-left: 5px }
.dropdown-btn-toolbar {
    margin-top: 9px;
    margin-bottom: 9px;
}
.dropdown-btn-toolbar .btn-group {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    /* IE7 inline-block hack */
    *zoom: 1;
}
.btn-group > .dropdown-btn {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
}
.btn-group > .dropdown-btn:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}
.btn-group > .dropdown-btn:last-child,
.btn-group > .dropdown-toggle {
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}
.btn-group > .dropdown-btn.large:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 6px;
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 6px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
}
.btn-group > .dropdown-btn.large:last-child,
.btn-group > .large.dropdown-toggle {
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 6px;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}
.btn-group > .dropdown-btn:hover,
.btn-group > .dropdown-btn:focus,
.btn-group > .dropdown-btn:active,
.btn-group > .dropdown-btn.active { z-index: 2 }
.btn-group .dropdown-toggle:active,
.btn-group.open .dropdown-toggle { outline: 0 }
.btn-group > .dropdown-toggle {
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.125), inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.125), inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    box-shadow: inset 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.125), inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    *padding-top: 4px;
    *padding-bottom: 4px;
}
.btn-group > .dropdown-btn-mini.dropdown-toggle {
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
.btn-group > .dropdown-btn-small.dropdown-toggle {
    *padding-top: 4px;
    *padding-bottom: 4px;
}
.btn-group > .dropdown-btn-large.dropdown-toggle {
    padding-left: 12px;
    padding-right: 12px;
}
.btn-group.open .dropdown-toggle {
    background-image: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}
.btn-group.open .dropdown-btn.dropdown-toggle { background-color: #e6e6e6 }
.btn-group.open .dropdown-btn-primary.dropdown-toggle { background-color: #0055cc }
.btn-group.open .dropdown-btn-warning.dropdown-toggle { background-color: #f89406 }
.btn-group.open .dropdown-btn-danger.dropdown-toggle { background-color: #bd362f }
.btn-group.open .dropdown-btn-success.dropdown-toggle { background-color: #51a351 }
.btn-group.open .dropdown-btn-info.dropdown-toggle { background-color: #2f96b4 }
.btn-group.open .dropdown-btn-inverse.dropdown-toggle { background-color: #222222 }
.dropdown-btn .caret {
    margin-top: 7px;
    margin-left: 0;
}
.dropdown-btn:hover .caret,
.open.btn-group .caret {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
.dropdown-btn-mini .caret { margin-top: 5px }
.dropdown-btn-small .caret { margin-top: 6px }
.dropdown-btn-large .caret {
    margin-top: 6px;
    border-left-width: 5px;
    border-right-width: 5px;
    border-top-width: 5px;
}
.dropup .dropdown-btn-large .caret {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #000000;
    border-top: 0;
}
.dropdown-btn-primary .caret,
.dropdown-btn-warning .caret,
.dropdown-btn-danger .caret,
.dropdown-btn-info .caret,
.dropdown-btn-success .caret,
.dropdown-btn-inverse .caret {
    border-top-color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 0.75;
    filter: alpha(opacity=75);
}
```

[Live demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/3R3EV/1/)

[Live demo (jsfiddle) updated](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/3R3EV/5/)

[Live demo(jsfiddle) updated 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/3R3EV/6/)

PS: don't try version 3 nor 4...

Comment: I've tried this approach already, but it breaks the toolbar-like design. I'd like my two buttons to be visually joined together, like in [button groups example](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonGroups). I'll update my question to make it more clear.

Comment: @SergeyKudriavtsev Updated, with a lot more styling. Seems to fit your description.

Comment: @SergeyKudriavtsev Last update (forgot some css code for the groups) and made a gist with the whole thing. Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could just add a CSS class to the btn-group divs and do this instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/plankmeister/JsPcg/

HTML:

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="pull-left">
                    <div class="btn-group btn-group-merge">
                        <a class="btn" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="icon icon-certificate"></i></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                             <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
                             <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                             <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
                        </ul>                            
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group btn-group-merge">
                        <a class="btn" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="icon icon-comment"></i></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                             <li><a href="#">A B C</a></li>
                             <li><a href="#">D E F</a></li>
                             <li><a href="#">G H I</a></li>
                        </ul>                            
                    </div>                        
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .navbar-fixed-top .btn-group-merge {
        margin-left : -5px;
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top .btn-group-merge:first-child {
        margin-left : 0;
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top .btn-group-merge .btn {
        border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top .btn-group-merge:first-child .btn {
        border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
    }
```

This will work with any number of buttons in the button group, but only the first and last will be rendered correctly. You could use some CSS-fu to fix it, but it wouldn't render on IE<10.

Answer (score 0):

Adding each set inside its own btn-group div did the trick for me.  Now each of the 2 drop downs appear on the same line and opens their related menu options correctly.  Just make sure the id for each set is unique. (SP 2016 OnPrem)

```
<div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" id="TranslatorActions" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" style="display:none"> Translator Actions <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul id="TranslatorActionsMenu" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu" aria-labelledby="TranslatorActions">
                <!–– Drop downs are added via script as needed -->
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" id="AdminActions" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" style="display:none">Admin Actions <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul id="AdminActionsMenu" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu" aria-labelledby="AdminActions">
                <li><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="OpenAdminForm();">Open Admin Form</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can use `id` and `aria-labelledby` attributes as described [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/dropdowns/)

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```